How to Redirect to an External URL with Headers in Next.js 14+
I'm working with Next.js 14+ and need to redirect a user from my Next.js server to an external URL. The catch is that I need to set a custom header before performing the redirect. However, I'm encountering an issue where the browser's URL doesn't change, even though can see in the browser's dev tools the redirect url status is 200 but the content and url didn't change in the browser? Is it because I'm using the fetch API on client?
So here's my current regular flow for all apis.
Fetch => nextjs server => external server
When I get a response from the external server I would like to redirect the user from nextjs server because I want to add some headers before redirecting to the external url.
I think it could be possible to redirect from nextjs action but not sure.
I used the following code in the server
res.setHeader('secret-header', 'some secret')
res.redirect(307, 'https://example.com')
res.writeHead(307, {Location: 'https://example.com'})
res.end()

